# Blender freeze for minutes while saving

Tags: saving

Blender freezes for minutes when i save a project , a render etc ... even if i try to save a simple box the issue is here . 
i have a surface book 2 GTX 1060 and CPU I7 , blender was working nicely until recently .
Does anybody has an idea ?

thank you .

Comment: Have you changed drivers, system settings or hardware? Such things don't happen just like that.

Comment: *blender was working nicely until recently* , what changed in your computer?

Comment: try load factory settings, maybe some hidden data stored in default scene

Answer (score 1):

When you save a file, it actually adds to the amount of memory being used in Blender currently. This happens to me quite often. When this gets bad enough, I usually save the file a last time, and then open the Blender file again. When I re-open the file, the previous saves' memory and history is not accounted for, and saving again is very quick.